# SSD Drive USB Power Issues (ADATA SU800)

Tags: ssd, power-management, usb-storage, external-drive

So I recently bought a brand new SSD Drive, ADATA SU800 1TB, and two USB enclosures to go with it. However, my laptop (surface pro 3) couldn't detect it in disk manager or `diskpart`, so I couldn't initialize it. Neither enclosure worked. Got it replaced, and same problem. I tried it on my desktop PC, and it was detected fine (through the enclosure). Here's the weird part. After unplugging it from my desktop, I could detect it on my laptop.

From my laptop, I think I was able to partition and format it too. But after a while, my laptop stopped detecting it. I could plug it back into my desktop and then plug it into my laptop and it would detect it fine again. And I could copy over some files fine. However, once I tried running CrystalDiskMark tests, the drive would lose connection. Note that I was also able to use a powered USB Hub and get it working and run the tests, but if I ever tried to run the tests without the hub, the drive would disconnect. If I ever left the drive untouched for a while, then the laptop wouldn't be able to detect it. So I have a feeling it's a power issue. My Raspberry Pi 2.0 USB ports were having the same problem, but my surface pro uses 3.0 ports so not sure why it's having problems.

Well anyways, because I was having issues even after I replaced the drive, I suspect its a problem with all SU800 drives. But ADATA refuses to give a refund. What do you guys think are my best options now?

UPDATE: luckily I was able to return the drive through Rakuten (the website I bought it from), thank god. I suspect it's an issue with ADATA drives and not just the one I received, so I'll keep the question up in case anybody else runs into the same issue.

Comment: *I have a feeling it's a power issue* I share your feelings and just because it's a USB3.0 port it doesn't mean it abides to the standard or could be damaged or the OS is managing it correctly or so many other possibilities. Because of that I understand and agree with the manufacturer's refusal: The product has been confirmed to work. That it doesn't in one specific machine isn't grounds for warranty claims.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I did read online that some people were having issues with the Surface Pro not detecting some drives. I also read some people having issues with the SU800 drive. So not sure which is the real problem. But whats also weird is that the SU800 didn't work on my Raspberry Pi unless I used a powered hub. My external disk drive (Seagate) was detected by my Raspi just fine, without the hub. I feel like the SSD should do the same, just maybe not reach maximum read/write speeds. But it's not being detected at all...

Comment: The Pi almost certainly can't power it by itself without ending up in a brownout condition.  Most SSD's are still designed for a nontrivial amount of power draw (the one in the laptop I'm currently using needs 1.2A for writes, which is way more than a Pi can provide).  Given this, power issues are my first guess too, followed by the USB-to-SATA chipset not properly negotiating the power draw (devices are supposed to negotiate, but some don't, and most hosts don't require it, but some do).

Comment: Whats interesting is my Raspi seems to be able to use my external disk drive just fine, but struggles with the SSD.  Don't disk drives require more power? And Yeah I was thinking it was a problem with the power negotiation as well, though I think I found a way the return the SSD so hopefully that works out